# Can't able to record jmeter with proxy server

Tags: proxy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I can't able to record jmeter using with proxy server.
I tried proxy settings in RUN command `jmeter.bat -H 192.168.61.202 -P 8080`.
Jmeter is recording with the browser actions, but not connecting the internet.
Showing error page on browser.
[See the screenshot- Error shown in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihW8z.png)

Answer (score 0):

are you able to record it using normal browser mode? If yes you should check for the firewall and add the specific port numbers to exclusions as some time back I faced the same issue, after i added the port number to excluded in Inbound and Outbound rules and disabling the antivirus setup on my machine made it work

Comment: We can get only the internet connection through proxy settings, even jmeter records this error messages comes in browser.

Comment: i understand :) . use the base connection on IE, which will ensure that internet connectivity is live. Use firefox to configure your local proxy using jmeter